# Having to Toggle Between Two Sets of Video Drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, performance, graphics-card, reinstall

So, I've got a Win7 64-bit gaming PC with GTX 260's.

Recently, StarCraft 2 had an issue with flickering, which NVidia fixed with a new set of drivers.

However, these new drivers induce unplayable graphical errors with Neverwinter Nights 2, something me and my friends still play from time to time.

I am seeking advice on the "best" way to rectify this situation, to be able to switch between two driver releases, without compromising the stability of my system (if Windows stability isn't an oxymoron).

I'm wondering if Windows 7 is structured in such a way that I can constantly reinstall these two sets of drivers back and forth overtop each other, possibly six or eight times a day, without very quickly driving myself to reformat to maintain that "just like new" performance.

I'm loathe to have to reformat the drive and maintain two copies of the operating system, but I'll do it if I have to.

Comment: Related question I asked (and left alone a bit since, admittedly): http://superuser.com/questions/32184/is-it-possible-to-automate-a-driver-change-on-windows-for-a-plugplay-peripheral. Not a duplicate, though, since changing video drivers probably involves more complications than a plug and play peripheral. Some answers could be shared, maybe.

Comment: Deleted my answer after reading Gnoupi's comment, I really think that question contributes more than my answer did.

Comment: @Dmatig - No reason to delete your answer for that. I was only linking this question, it is not an answer in itself.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the logical question is do you have the latest patches for Neverwinter Nights 2? I would check out http://nwn.bioware.com/support/patch.html

Comment: Don't treat the "gaming" question, though. Treat rather the driver question.

Comment: I don't understand your comment - if Starcraft 2 runs fine with the latest drivers but, an older game, Neverwinter Nights 2 does not...it stands to reason that there is a bug in the older game and not with the driver. You should not have to switch drivers to play 2 different games. Especially since Neverwinter Nights 2 is not that old of a game.

Comment: I mean simply that gaming questions are off-topic on Super User. Troubleshooting why this game doesn't work with these drivers is out of scope. This is why I recommend you to focus on the "switch graphical drivers" core of the question.

Comment: I think that is a fallacious point. Just because a solution that falls outside the scope of the site - doesn't mean it shouldn't be concerned, it just means that it won't be investigated beyond "we tried this, ok next". It's common practice in troubleshooting/repair, run through a set of common solutions to a given problem or similar problem.